# 1998 Chevy won't run

Tags: engine, starting, chevrolet

1998 Chevy truck 5.7 Vortec engine won't run unless I take #3 plug wire off engine dies when it is put back on have checked everything including blinker fluid

Comment: What have you checked specifically?

Comment: Blinker fluid? Surely you jest...

Comment: Asking to leave this open as the OP has answered the question themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably put the spark plug wires wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It was not spark plugs ... it was the Distributer cap! I hope this helps someone in the future from spending $500 on unneeded parts Just put one on from Advance Auto 60 days ago

Comment: And to those who'd have this deleted as NAA, this ***is*** the answer, posted by the OP.